# Which browser loading issue

Tags: javascript, browser, async-await, waithandle

I am using whichbrowser javascript. I am creating the object to access this script. When I am creating the object, this script is not loading in my browser, so that it stops the javascirpt file execution. How can I know whether the script is loaded or not?

Comment: You have presented no code, and my crystal ball is murky today. Unless you add much more relevant information, your vague question will likely receive no answers. Also, [tag:async-await] and [tag:waithandle] don't seem to have anything to do with your question, and [tag:which] is meant for SQL queries.

Answer (score -1):

You can use chrome dev tools network panel for this.In network tab look for the js if it has downloaded with a 200 status response or not.